# Recursive function filling stack

Tags: jquery, animation, recursion, queue, recursive-query

I have a wobble animation function that I've created, however at a certain point I want to destroy the bound animation in the stack, however when I do this, I receive an error:

`Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

This is obviously because I'm filling up the whole stack, however I'm wondering if there's a better way to execute the following animation but still creating a smooth way to stop it when I want?

```
function wobble(targetElement, speed, distance) {
    targetElement.animate({ marginLeft: "+=" + distance}, {
        complete: function () {             
            targetElement.animate({ marginLeft: "-=" + distance}, {
                complete: function () {
                    wobble(targetElement, speed, distance, status);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I was using `finish()` to kill the queue and stop the animation, this is how I got this error.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested the code but you could try something like this:

```
    var count=0;
    function wobble(targetElement, speed, distance,count) {
        if (count < 50){
            targetElement.animate({ marginLeft: "+=" + distance}, {
                 complete: wobble (targetElement, speed, distance,count++);
             }
        }
   });
```

Second solution (without testing the code)

```
var continue=true;
function wobble(targetElement, speed, distance) {
    if (continue){
        targetElement.animate({ marginLeft: "+=" + distance}, {
            complete: wobble (targetElement, speed, distance);
        });
    }
};
```

//when you want to finish "wobbling" you just have to set "continue" variable to false, example

```
$('button.stop').on('click',function(){
      console.log("wobbling stopped");
      continue=false;
});
```

So the main point is that you need something (a flag), that tells to "wobble" method to STOP. In this case, the flag will be "continue" variable which will changed from "true" to "false" when you want.

Comment: I don't want to limit the function though, I just want to be able to stop it at a time of my pleasing, not when a loop counter bubbles up

Comment: Alvaro do you have a solution?

Comment: That's pretty much the exact same function as mine, the stack will still propagate this way